# have a java web service return a Null Web Result

Tags: java, web-services

I have a Java web service that when no item is found I want a null object to be returned.  Instead, I'm getting back an instance with all properties set to null. I can check for the item having a null property, but would prefer the item returned itself to be Null.

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name="item")
public item findItem(
            @WebParam(name="Id") int Id){
  //...
  if(ItemNotFound(Id)){
    return null;
  }
}
```

On the client side, the wsItem is NOT null

```
item wsItem=ws.findItem(1);
if(wsItem==null){
  // this will not be hit
}
```

Checking the item property will work on the client side

```
item wsItem=ws.findItem(1);
    if(wsItem.Property1==null){
      // this will
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you've given, I don't understand why you can't simply do

```
if(item.getProperties() == null)
    return null;
```

EDIT:
Okay, now that you've updated with more code, I have a better idea of what's going on. Can you set some breakpoints? Are you sure that `ItemNotFound` is returning `true`, and that you're actually reaching the `return null` line in your service code? Something extra-kooky would have to be going on for the client code to be responsible, since I don't see the `new` keyword anywhere in there.

EDIT 2:
I initially approached this as a pure Java problem, but based on your latest comment, that's not true. It was pointed out in the chat that this is probably has to do with your annotations, or some other kind of broader settings.

Comment: it is very easy for a developer to have if(item==null) instead and not realize the return is not valid since all its properties are null.

Comment: To further elaborate, the web service DOES return null. The consumer sees an actual item with all Null properties.

Comment: I can't understand what you want help with. Here's my understanding so far: Your service gets an ID. If there is an item with that ID, you return it. If there isn't, you want to return `null`, and that is currently what you are doing. You do not want to return a dummy item will `null` properties. Am I understanding the situation wrong? Are you looking for help with the client-side code?

Comment: Even though the web service is returning Null, on the client side the item is not Null, only its properties.

Comment: I checked everything you asked for and the web service is returning Null. I think this is a feature of a Java Web Service.

Comment: Yeah I looked up the @WebResult annotation documentation for Java but didn't see something like nillable. I'm looking to see if I can set some annotation on the actual return class declaration.